# How to set maximum width of a site to certain percentage?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to set the maximum width of my site using css. I tried using setting the body width to 100% before I set the  for maximum width to 80%. If I didn't set body width to 100% before I would have my assets move slightly to left and I have no idea why.

Here is the code for the thing.

```css
html,body{ 
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:grey;
    font-color:white;
    font-style: none;
}
```

and then the Div.

```css
#sirka{
   max-width:80%;
}
```

Does somebody know why does it move my text+images slightly to the left if I dont include the starting width in the body css ?

Answer (score 3):

html elements have default values (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) you have to overwrite them if you don't want them

for example u can write

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The percentage width setting only depends if the parent has a width specified or parent's display.

This is not new, look demos below:

```css
html,body{ 
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:grey;
    font-color:white;
    font-style: none;
}


.sirka{
   max-width:80%;
}

/* ADDED */
.sirka{
  background-color:red;
  height: 50px;
}
.d-flex{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="sirka"> width max no parent display</div>
<div class="d-flex"><div class="sirka"> no width max because parents display</div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Would adding

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

make it work ?